# middleware gets executed for every request without specify a mount path

Tags: go

Node.js Express can insert a middleware with no mount path, and it gets executed for every request.  Is there a way to accomplish that in GO?

```
var app = express();

// a middleware with no mount path; gets executed for every request to the app
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now());
  next();
});
```

Comment: That'd depend on which framework you're using, if any. The obvious answer is "of course, you can do anything in essentially any language".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example with Go's `net/http`:

```
func main() {
   r := http.NewServeMux()
   r.HandleFunc("/some-route", SomeHandler)

   // Wrap your *ServeMux with a function that looks like
   // func SomeMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler   
   http.ListenAndServe("/", YourMiddleware(r))
}
```

Middleware might be something like this:

```
func YourMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
   fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       // Do something with the response
       w.Header().Set("Server", "Probably Go")
       // Call the next handler
       h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
   }

   // Type-convert our function so that it
   // satisfies the http.Handler interface
   return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

If you have a lot of middleware you want to chain, a package like [alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) can simplify it so you're not `Wrapping(AllOf(YourMiddleware(r))))` like that. You could also write your own helper -

```
func use(h http.Handler, middleware ...func(http.Handler) http.Handler) http.Handler {
    for _, m := range middleware {
        h = m(h)
    }
    return h
}

// Example usage:
defaultRouter := use(r, handlers.LoggingHandler, csrf.Protect(key), CORSMiddleware)
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", defaultRouter)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is quite helpful.